# Upgrade SQL Server 2008 R2 to 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I just upgraded from SQL Server 2008 R2 to SQL Server 2012 but, when opening SQL Server Management Studio and check for the server edition `(Help | About)` it still shows 2008 R2.
[image]

The upgrade seemed to work ok, but do I have to reinstall SQL Server 2012?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Help > About just shows the version of Management Studio, not SQL Server. Just like Help > About in Word shows the version of Word, not the version of Windows.

Connect to the server and check `SELECT @@VERSION;`. Also check the SQL Server 2012 program folder; you should be using a new version of Management Studio found there. Should be something like:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\Ssms.exe

SQL Server 2012 built a brand new version of Management Studio, and as such, unlike when upgrading from 2005 to 2008 or 2008 R2, it allows you to keep the old version of SSMS side-by-side. But really you should be using the newer version of the client tools in almost all cases.